# Barba.js not loading img

Tags: javascript, image

I'm using Barba.js and layzload and I have a big problem.
When the page change, my animation works, but the images on the new page are not loaded (without error message), as you can see on the screenshot below (page in french but the images are on the bottom).
If i refresh the page, the images are loaded, so the problem is, 'how to load the images on page change ?'

[Screenshot : Images are not loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1hiQ.png).

My code on index.html :

```
<body id="body-home" >
    <div id="barba-wrapper">
        <div class="barba-container" data-namespace="homepage">
           [some basic stuff]
            // My link to a project
            <a href="pirates-des-caraibes.html">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

My code on a project (images don't load) :

```
<body id="body-projet" class="project">
    <div id="barba-wrapper">
        <div class="barba-container" data-namespace="projet">

            <img data-original="assets/images/pirates/mockup_pirates_home.jpg" alt="" class="lazy" />
             <img data-original="assets/images/pirates/mockup_pirates_lots.jpg" alt="" class="lazy" />

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

My barba script :

```
var pageTransition = function () {

    var FadeTransition = Barba.BaseTransition.extend({
        start: function () {
            Promise
            .all([this.newContainerLoading, this.fadeOut()])
            .then(this.fadeIn.bind(this));
        },

        fadeOut: function() {
            $('.cache').addClass('.active');
            return $(this.oldContainer).animate({opacity: 0}).promise();
        },

        fadeIn: function() {
            var _this = this;
            var $el = $(this.newContainer);

            $(this.oldContainer).hide();
            document.body.scrollTop = 0;

            $el.css({
                visibility: 'visible',
                opacity: 0
            });

            $el.animate({opacity: 1}, 400, function () {
                _this.done();
            });
        }
    });

    var Homepage = Barba.BaseView.extend({
        namespace: 'homepage',
        onEnter: function() {
        },
        onEnterCompleted: function() {
        },
        onLeave: function() {
        },
        onLeaveCompleted: function() {
        }
    });

    Homepage.init();

    var Projets = Barba.BaseView.extend({
        namespace: 'projet',
        onEnter: function() {
        },
        onEnterCompleted: function() {
            // Some animations when the page load
            $('.overlay-header').addClass('active');
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.container-header').fadeIn();
            }, 500);

            //col-1
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.col-1>.overlay-col').addClass('active');
            }, 700);

            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.col-1>h4').css('opacity', '1');
                $('.col-1>p').css('opacity', '1');
            }, 800);

            //col-2
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.col-2>.overlay-col').addClass('active');
            }, 1100);

            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.col-2>h4').css('opacity', '1');
                $('.col-2 li').css('opacity', '1');
            }, 1200);

            //col-3
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.col-3>.overlay-col').addClass('active');
            }, 1500);

            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.col-3>h4').css('opacity', '1');
                $('.col-3 li').css('opacity', '1');
            }, 1600);
        },
        onLeave: function() {
        },
        onLeaveCompleted: function() {
        }
    });

    Projets.init();

    Barba.Pjax.getTransition = function () {
        return FadeTransition;
    };

    Barba.Pjax.start();
};

var run = function () {
    pageTransition();
};

run();
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: Going to have to provide code for us to help...

Comment: Yes, sorry. Post edited